# how to set text over video in html on different sizes

Tags: html, css

I want to put text over video in `html` which works fine on my laptop screen but when I change size from toggle device toolbar the video is in right position while text go down so how should I dynamically set text over video in `html`.

my code

```
<video loop="loop" style="position: relative;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;" autoplay muted>
  <source src="/assets/images/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<section id="hero" class="d-flex align-items-center">    
  <div class="container" data-aos="zoom-out" data-aos-delay="100">
    <h1>University Courses</h1>
    <h3>YOUR FIRST CHOICE IN ARABIC AND ISLAMIC STUDIES</h3>
    <div class="d-flex">
      <a href="#about" class="btn-get-started scrollto" style="font-size: 18px;">ENQUIRE HERE<i class="fas fa-arrow-right" style="padding-left: 5px;"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

my css

```
#hero {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}
#hero h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 56px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS file is wrong. If you want to add text in class container, you must write in this way:

```
.container h1{
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 56px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.d-flex{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}
```